# Can not load dylib on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, apple-m1, dyld

I'm trying to inject a simple dynamic library on MacOS in different binary files.

This is my simple dynamic library: `inject.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
static void myCusomConstructor()
{
    printf("Hello from dylib\n");
}
```

I compile it with `gcc -dynamiclib inject.c -o libinject.dylib`.
And then when I try to inject it in `/bin/ls` binary by `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/user/libinject.dylib /bin/ls` I get an error:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Users/user/libinject.dylib' because no suitable image found. Did find:
    /Users/user/libinject.dylib: incompatible cpu-subtype: 0x00000000 in /Users/user/libinject.dylib
    /Users/user/libinject.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/user/libinject.dylib /bin/ls
```

So, what I am doing wrong?
I run this test on MacBook Pro 2020 with Apple M1 and MacOS Big Sur.

#### More info about issue

Output for `file /bin/ls`:

```bash
/bin/ls: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/bin/ls (for architecture x86_64):      Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/bin/ls (for architecture arm64e):      Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

So, on my machine `/bin/ls` is a fat binary.

Also, I tried to compile `inject.c` for different CPU architectures:

*arm64*: `gcc -arch arm64 -dynamiclib inject.c -o libinject-arm64.dylib`

Output:

```bash
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Users/user/libinject-arm64.dylib' because no suitable image found. Did find:
    /Users/user/libinject-arm64.dylib: incompatible cpu-subtype: 0x00000000 in /Users/user/libinject-arm64.dylib
    /Users/user/libinject-arm64.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/user/libinject-arm64.dylib /bin/ls
```

*arm64e*: `gcc -arch arm64e -dynamiclib inject.c -o libinject-arm64e.dylib`

Output:

```bash
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Users/user/libinject-arm64e.dylib' because no suitable image found. Did find:
    /Users/user/libinject-arm64e.dylib: incompatible cpu-subtype: 0x00000002 in /Users/user/libinject-arm64e.dylib
    /Users/user/libinject-arm64e.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/user/libinject-arm64e.dylib /bin/ls
```

*x86_64*: `gcc -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib inject.c -o libinject-x86.dylib`

Output:

```bash
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Users/user/libinject-x86.dylib' because no suitable image found. Did find:
    /Users/user/libinject-x86.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/user/libinject-x86.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/user/libinject-x86.dylib /bin/ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the libinject.dylib library and /bin/ls are for different cpu architectures. For example being Intel and Arm.

Try with the Xcode c compiler (clang).
It appears working on newer version of macOS with clang. I understand from comments it will be difficult to upgrade your development environment.

Edit: I just found a deeper explanation:

> [More Info](https://theevilbit.github.io/posts/dyld_insert_libraries_dylib_injection_in_macos_osx_deep_dive/)

Comment: Yes, you are right, my example was borrowed from [this](https://theevilbit.github.io/posts/dyld_insert_libraries_dylib_injection_in_macos_osx_deep_dive/) article.

Also, I added some more architecture specific info in my question, have a look.

Comment: Tried gcc -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -arch arm64 -dynamiclib inject.c -o libinject-arm64.dylib

Output: `/Users/user/libinject-x86.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`

Also -std=c++20 didn't help.
Moreover this example works fine on Linux machine. So, it seems like only MacOS issue.

Comment: No, it didn't help me. Output is the same: `no matching architecture in universal wrapper`.
Also, is it possible that I can't load dylib due to SIP?

Comment: My testing environment was set up on Big Sur 11.1 and I do not really want to upgrade the system. Maybe you know some other tricks to execute code before start of a new process (in my example /bin/ls)?